# How to make parameterized Postgres in TO_DATE()

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I need to create parameterized query to prevent SQL injection.

The query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT USER_ID, COUNT(USER_ID) USER_ID_CNT FROM s.sample
    WHERE (SCH_DPRT_GMT_TS >= TO_DATE(?, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') 
    AND  SCH_DPRT_GMT_TS <= TO_DATE(?, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')) 
    AND USER_ID IS NOT NULL GROUP BY USER_ID ORDER BY USER_ID
```

The prepared statement I am creating is:

```
try (Connection connection = agroalDataSource.getConnection();
     PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(finalSQL)) {
  if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(SchDprtTs1) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(SchDprtTs2)) {
    pstmt.setString(1, SchDprtTs1);
    pstmt.setString(2, SchDprtTs1);
  }
}
```

I am getting a `NullPointerException` as `pstmt` is always `null`. I am new to Postgres. How can I resolve this?

Comment: `TO_DATE` function does not seem to exist in MySQL (maybe [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)).

Comment: sorry It is postgres.

Comment: It should be just `?` (with no quotes).

Comment: Yes ,I removed ' ' but still getting prepared statement as null

Comment: @Olivier While debugging I can see pstmt.setString(1,SchDprtTs1 ) ; while executing this statement ,the controller is directly going to return resultset  instead of going to 2nd setString .

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible for `pstmt` to be `null`.  According to the javadocs, the `prepareStatement` call will either return a new `PreparedStatement` object or it will throw an exception.  There is no scenario in which it would return `null` ... according to the javadoc.

Therefore ... the `NullPointerException` must be caused by something else, possibly in code that you have not shown us.

---

In my experience, Java debuggers can be misleading.

My recommendation would be to read the full stacktrace for the NPE to find the source line on which the NPE was thrown.  Then list all of the operations on that line that *could* have thrown an NPE, analyse each of them, and eliminate those that are impossible<sup>1</sup>.  If more than one possibility remains, use strategic trace print statements to narrow it down to the actual cause.

<sup>1 - In this case, `prepareStatement` could only return `null` if there is a ridiculously obvious bug in the Postgres driver.  I'm inclined to discount that possibility.</sup>